# jQuery и :after

Tags: jquery

```
div {
    height:45px;
    border:0px;
    line-height:45px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
div:after {
    content:""; 
    background: darkgreen; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height:10%; 
    width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Taypfoon/o9z2274L

Как с помощью jQuery изменить свойства `div:after` ?
Например раз в секунду увеличивать высоту `div:after` на 10%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример на ванильном js

```js
var currentHeight = 10;
var delta = 10;

function setPseudoClass(elclass, prop, value) {
  var sheets = document.styleSheets;
  var slen = sheets.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < slen; i++) {
    var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
    if (rules) {
      var rlen = rules.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < rlen; j++) {
        if (rules[j].selectorText == elclass) {
          rules[j].style[prop] = value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  if (currentHeight >= 100) {
    delta = -10;
  } else if (currentHeight <= 10) {
    delta = 10;
  }
  currentHeight += delta;
  setPseudoClass("div::after", "height", currentHeight + "%");
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  height: 45px;
  border: 0px;
  line-height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  background: darkgreen;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Привет</div>
<div>Ещё Привет</div>
```

Comment: Зачем все эти пляски с бубном, если в вопросе явно указан jQuery?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev у меня тоже была такая проблема, положил себе в набор сниппетов и сейчас ему скинул то, что у меня было. Если автору подойдет этот **нормальный** способ, то пусть использует, если не понравится, то он сам напишет. Если знаете как сделать это на jquery, то никто вам не запретит предложить вариант, который возможно станет ему по душе. Да и вообще переходите на светлую сторону http://vanilla-js.com

Answer (score 0):

Пример реализации на jQuery

Демо с интервалом: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGRvjz

Решение не изящное, иначе никак. jQuery не работает с `:before`, `:after`

```
var height = 20;

$("<style type='text/css' id='dynamic' />").appendTo("head");
$("#dynamic").text("div:after{height: "+height+"%;}");
```